# Cannot target .NET Framework 4.6.1

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I try to load an existing project (not mine) that I get from TFS and I got an error telling me that I need .NET Framework 4.6.1 to load it.

So I downgraded it to 4.6, successfully load it, install .NET Framework 4.6.1 but I can't make my project target on 4.6.1.

[image: Target framework]

The link where I get  [.NET framework](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=49981)

I'm on Windows 7 and I use Visual Studio Community 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to install the developer pack. It looks like you may have just installed the runtime. You can find the .NET Framework 4.6.1 developer pack [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978).

Comment: I already have installed the dev pack, so I tried to repair the installation and now it works.. thank you :)

Comment: @Morgan If this solved your problem, please feel free to mark it as the answer. It's helpful for me and everyone else down the road to know what did the trick for you.